# Second Monitor for Laptop not displaying correctly

Tags: laptop, display, multiple-monitors, external-display, docking-station

so, I've just bought a docking station for my hp elite book and tried to hook it up. Following problem occured:

- when plugging in an dp cable from the docking station to the monitor the laptop will recognize the monitor but the monitor will just display a black screen.

First I thought there was something wrong with the docking station because I tried the monitor and the dp cable with my pc and it worked, but then I pluged in a dp to hdmi cable from the dp output of my docking station into the monitor and it displayed the screen.

So far so good, but the problem that I am facing now is that the dimensions are off. The size shown in the settings is 2560x1600(recommended) but when plugging the monitor into my regular pc it shows 3840x2160(recommended) which is the 4k resolution my monitor has. So when plugging the monitor into my docking station i have a black bars at the top and the bottom of the screen and a blurry effect. The strange thing is if I plug the dp cable right into my laptop - not the docking station - the display shows up normaly. There is also no correct option to change the resolution in the settings.

Any idea how to fix this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: sounds like your laptop may not support the same 3840x2160 resolution your PC does - make sure all of your drivers are updated (display, docking station, etc.) and consult your laptop's manual for the resolutions its GPU can handle. Once everything is updated you'll just need to find a resolution that works and may have to also tinker with the monitor's scaling.

Comment: what is the model of the docking station and of the monitor?

Comment: @mael at first I thought the same, but when plugging the display into the so output of the laptop directly all shows up normally.